# pgadmin is only returning 1000 rows for a query on a table with over 225000 rows

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

When I SELECT * or commit any query for this particular database all that pgadmin returns is 1000 rows even thought there are over 225000. This hasn't been the case since I imported the data but began suddenly and I am unsure of the cause. I have the latest version(4.23). This doesn't happen on another database that has over 1000 rows. The row limit drop down is greyed out. I've check the documentation for an answers in the documentation and checked around for similar questions elsewhere but I have not found any answers. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if you want to display 225000 rows with pgAdmin, you'll wait forever. That tool is known to be fast as a glacier for large result sets. Use something like `psql` instead.

Comment: Why would you want to _display_ 225000 rows?

Comment: Have you tried to run ANALYZE on the database?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't want all 225000 it's more out of curiosity as to why it won't return more than 1000 when it has with other databases

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have not but I will try that. Still in the beginning stages of learning all of this

Answer (score 7):

Changing the parameter in config.py pgAdmin4/web folder

```
##########################################################################
# Number of records to fetch in one batch in query tool when query result
# set is large.
##########################################################################
ON_DEMAND_RECORD_COUNT = 100000000
```

Comment: Tried that on a 6.20 version, did not work.