# How to select all rows PostgreSQL more than 1000 rows

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I can't select more than 1000 rows in pgAdmin .. any help please !

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595257/pgadmin-is-only-returning-1000-rows-for-a-query-on-a-table-with-over-225000-rows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pgadmin is only returning 1000 rows for a query on a table with over 225000 rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62595257/pgadmin-is-only-returning-1000-rows-for-a-query-on-a-table-with-over-225000-rows)

Answer (score 0):

File-Preferences-Query Tool-Graph Visualiser

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).